# I want to delete row in googlesheet using googlesheet api v4

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

I want to delete a row using rowno in googlesheet using googlesheetv4 api.
Can anybody provide me a sample code for this?
I have created a method for delete row:

```
public void deleteRow() {

    BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest content = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
    Request request = new Request();
    request.setDeleteDimension(new DeleteDimensionRequest().setRange(new DimensionRange().setDimension("D30:D31")));

    List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<Request>();
    requests.add(request);
    content.setRequests(requests);
    System.out.println(content.getRequests());

    try {
        service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(IConstant.SPREADSHEET_ID, content);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code looks close, but you aren't setting up the `DimensionRange` correctly. Try the following:

```
Request request = new Request()
  .setDeleteDimension(new DeleteDimensionRequest()
    .setRange(new DimensionRange()
      .setSheetId(0)
      .setDimension("ROWS")
      .setStartIndex(30)
      .setEndIndex(32)
    )
  );
```

Comment: thanks Eric now my requirement is to delete only selected rows can u please provide me a sample for this

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in [Migrate to the Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/migration), to [delete a row](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/migration#delete_a_row) using Google Sheets API V4, is handled by a `spreadsheet.batchUpdate` method call, using a `DeleteDimension` request. This request can also be used to remove columns, and developers can choose to only remove part of a row or column.

**Example Code which removes the 6th row of a sheet with the given ID:**

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId:batchUpdate

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "deleteDimension": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "dimension": "ROWS",
          "startIndex": 5,
          "endIndex": 6
        }
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

More information in [row and column operations](https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/rowcolumn) might help.

Comment: I know this and i have already read this but i want to know java example for this

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but you have to make sure that you execute the request. My code basically combined both of your results together.

```
    BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest content = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
    Request request = new Request()
        .setDeleteDimension(new DeleteDimensionRequest()
          .setRange(new DimensionRange()
            .setSheetId(Integer.parseInt(Defines.GRID_ID))
            .setDimension("ROWS")
            .setStartIndex(30)
            .setEndIndex(30 + numofrows)
          )
        );

    // request.setDeleteDimension(new DeleteDimensionRequest().setRange(new DimensionRange().setDimension("D30:D31")));

    List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<Request>();
    requests.add(request);
    content.setRequests(requests);

    try {
        sheetsService.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(Defines.GOOGLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, content).execute();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my approach is best one or not but it is serving the purpose, so I'll explain what I did.

1. Keep one extra column(say ROWNUM) in the sheet where you are saving
   data.
2. Write same string "=ROW()" in this column each time when
   you're posting data, it will generate the row id for that row
3. Then utilize the following method, hope it helps!

   ```
   public void deleteRows (String range, String textToBeDeleted) {//textToBeDeleted is cell value which will be find in the column and that row will be deleted

   try {
       Sheets sheetsService = createSheetsService();
       ValueRange response = sheetsService.spreadsheets().values()
               .get(spreadsheetId, range)
               .execute(); //Getting all the data of the sheet

       List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();
       List<List<Object>> allData = response.getValues();
       List<Integer> rowsToBeDeleted = new ArrayList<>();

       for (List<Object> row : allData) {
           if (row.get(0).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(textToBeDeleted)) { //0 is the column value based on which I'll be deleting the row
               rowsToBeDeleted.add(Integer.parseInt(row.get(23).toString())); //23 is the RowNumber column in my case
           }
       }

       BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest requestBody = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
       for (int i = rowsToBeDeleted.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) { //Reverse loop while deleting so that wrong index doesn't get deleted
           Request request = new Request();
           request.setDeleteDimension(new DeleteDimensionRequest()
                   .setRange(new DimensionRange()
                           .setSheetId(sheetid)
                           .setDimension("ROWS")
                           .setStartIndex(rowsToBeDeleted.get(i) - 1)
                           .setEndIndex(rowsToBeDeleted.get(i))
                   )
           );
           requests.add(request);
       }
       requestBody.setRequests(requests);

       Sheets.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate deleteRequest =
               sheetsService.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, requestBody);

       BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse deleteResponse = deleteRequest.execute();

       System.out.println(deleteResponse);

   } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
   }}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct but the few mistakes are:

1. In my case the `sheetId` is `0` and it works.
2. You must have google permissions, to update the sheet.
   Go to [Google OAuth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). Search for google sheets v4 and select all the options and then authorise for the access token and copy the access token, the code example is:

```js
const deleteRow = async (rowIndex: number) => {
    setBusy(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sheet_id}:batchUpdate`,
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: 'Bearer' + YOUR_TOKEN,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            requests: [
              {
                deleteDimension: {
                  range: {
                    sheetId: 0, // number after gid=0 in your url
                    dimension: 'ROWS',
                    startIndex: rowIndex,
                    endIndex: rowIndex + 1,
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
          }),
        },
      );
      console.log(await response.json());
    } catch (err: any) {
      console.log(err.message);
    } finally {
      // refetch the data
      setBusy(false);
      handleFetch();
    }
  };
```

This is not a production code, we will have to save the token while we login, this was an example for the spreadsheet to work.